api is working when i use postman but when i use the same api in my react app it is giving me this error net::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID
api is working when i use postman but when i use the same api in my react app it is giving me this error net::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID getting this error on the consolecode where i made the post request
When I run the api locally I am able to hit the end point using react app ,but when the same api is deployed and after that I am trying to hit the endpoint , It is giving me this error

That error indicates an invalid SSL certificate. When running locally, the browser and postman would ignore the SSL issue since it trusts your localhost, but once deployed it expects a valid SSL. You may need to install a SSL certificate, or switch to using HTTP only. Free SSL are pretty easy these days, checkout Certbot and LetsEncrypt

If you are using HTTPS protocol with a local proxy server, as part of your development process, then you may have a certificate issue as the remote and the local one may not match or signed by different vendors (your local one may be self signed and does not enable specific IPs or enable only specific ones).
Try to stop the local proxy server and remove the certificate from your machine. Make sure that it is not re-added. There are many explanations online on how to do this. Should be easier in mac
